# redis how to get Sorted Set Member with Score?

Tags: redis

I am new to Redis.

```sh
127.0.0.1:6379> zadd myset 1 'one'
(integer) 1
127.0.0.1:6379> zadd myset 2 'two'
(integer) 1
127.0.0.1:6379> zadd myset 3 'three' 4 'four' 
(integer) 2
127.0.0.1:6379> zadd myset 10 'ten' 9 'nine'
(integer) 2
```

I tried ZRANGEBYSCORE, but it shows member only..

```sh
127.0.0.1:6379> ZRANGEBYSCORE myset -inf +inf
1) "one"
2) "two"
3) "three"
4) "four"
5) "nine"
6) "ten"
```

But I want to get Score / Member pairs.

How can I get these pairs ?

Comment: you need to add `WITHSCORES` at the end, `ZRANGEBYSCORE myset -inf +inf WITHSCORES`

Comment: Thanks for reply. you are right.. but I am looking for kinds of way  of array or list style expression.. Is it impossible in Redis ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Ersoy already commented:

> you need to add `WITHSCORES` at the end, `ZRANGEBYSCORE myset -inf +inf WITHSCORES`

The reply is sent in a format as follows:

```
1) MEMBER_1
2) SCORE_1
3) MEMBER_2
4) SCORE_1
...
```

If you want the reply as a list/array of *pair*, like:

```
1) MEMBER_1, SCORE_1
2) MEMBER_2, SCORE_2
...
```

Any sane Redis client<sup>[1]</sup>, even in your preferred language, is likely to convert it as such.

[1] not including redis-cli